# The Double Click Event Problem of Child Items in Treeview Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

After double clicking on the child item of the treeview control in wpf, Expanded or MouseDoubleClick will execute twice
TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick or TreeViewItem_Expanded How to solve the problem where I execute twice when I double-click on a sub item

```
  `<TreeView
         x:Name="Tree_Channel"
         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />
         <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick"  Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>

  public Window1()
        {
     InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

        TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();


        var rootNode1 = new TreeNode("Root 1");
        var rootNode2 = new TreeNode("Root 2");     
        rootNode1.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Child 1"));
        rootNode1.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Child 2"));
        rootNode2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Child 3"));
        rootNode2.Children.Add(new TreeNode("Child 4"));     
        TreeItems.Add(rootNode1);
        TreeItems.Add(rootNode2);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> TreeItems { get; set; }
    private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }  
    public class TreeNode

    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }

        public TreeNode(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
        }
    }

    private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue you have is that parent item also handle mouse double click. You can filter it in the handler.

```
private void TreeViewItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Return, if parent item handler
    if (sender != e.OriginalSource)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = null;

        var visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement);
        while (tvi == null && visParent != null)
        {
            tvi = visParent as TreeViewItem;
            visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visParent);
        }
        if (tvi == null || tvi != sender)                    
        {
            return; 
        }
    }

    e.Handled = true; // Stop expand behavior on double click
}
```

Comment: thx,e.Handled = true at expand Valid，at doubleclick invalid ,But it works